# How to convert string to floating point number inside a Perl hash?

Tags: perl

My motive is to convert the string number into floating point number while creating a hash.

I have placed my entire code and error below. Please help me to solve this issue.

**Sample code**

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my $price = 8.5;

my $g={};
$g->{'get'}=sprintf('%.02f',$price);

print Dumper($g);
```

**Current output**

```
$VAR1 = {
          'get' => '8.50'
        };
```

**Expected output**

```
$VAR1 = {
          'get' => 8.50
        };
```

Comment: "floating point integer" is a bit confusing since numbers are either floating point or integer. One could perhaps argue that `3.0` is such a beast but when it comes to programming, numbers are stored and operated on as either floating points or as integers. Or as strings even since the topic is perl. Many if not all dynamic languages (perl included) can treat strings as numbers if they look like a number: `perl -le 'print " 44.2 " + " -.342e1 " '` => `40.78`

Answer (score 1):

Despite the single quotes around `8.50` in the `Dumper` output, Perl will still treat it as a numeric value when you go to use it:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $price = 8.5;

my $g={};
$g->{'get'}=sprintf('%.02f',$price);

my $x = 5;
printf "%.02f\n", $x + $g->{get};
```

Outputs:

```
13.50
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use Scalar::Util 'looks_like_number';
.
.
print Dumper($g) =~ s/'(.*?)'/looks_like_number($1)?$1:"'$1'"/ger;
```

Which changes the output from Dumper before it's printed. It removes both `'`s of every single quoted string if it looks like a number according to Scalar::Util.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're worrying unnecessarily here. Perl treats strings and numbers as largely interchangeable and will generally do the right thing with data of either type. The number of times when you should care if you have a string or a number is tiny.

In fact, even if you explicitly give Perl a number in code like yours, it will be displayed as a string:

```
$ perl -MData::Dumper -E'say Dumper { get => 8.5 }'
$VAR1 = {
          'get' => '8.5'
        };
```

Comment: I am dynamically creating this hash and sent it to some other Rest-API application.Where this get value need to be a integer

Comment: @DeepakRaj: if it needs to be an integer, why does your example use a floating-point number? What format are you calling the API with? Is it JSON? Your problem is not here, it's with the JSON that is being created. Please close this question and start a new one about that.